# Find files modified over 1 hour ago but less than 3 days

Tags: linux, bash

In linux, using bash, what's the easiest way to find files that were modified more than an hour ago but less than 3 days ago?

Surely, there's got to be an easy way to do this. I keep searching and can't find an easy solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Find has -mtime and -mmin:

```
find . -mtime +3 -mmin -60
```

From the find manual:

> Numeric arguments can be specified as:
>
> +n for greater than n
>
> -n for less than n
>
> n for exactly n

Comment: Could you elaborate on this a bit? I just tried on two bash shells on 2 different computers, and neither support the "-greater" option

Comment: Sorry, keyboard faster than the brain issue here :(. Updated

Comment: One more thing. I tried the example and it seems like you need to add "+" and "-" to make it work, eg: `find . -mtime -30 -mmin +60`

Comment: Yes, was writing that along with the excerpt. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This should suffice: `find . -mtime -3 -mmin +60`

I just tried it:

`find ./ -mtime -3 -mmin +60 -exec ls -lhrt {} \; | awk '{print $5" "$6" "$7" "$8}'`