# How can I find files in a git repo that have not been modified in X time?

Tags: git

Is there a way to find files in a git repository based on the time since they were last modified?

Comment: Like: finding all files that have been modified less than 4 days ago?

Comment: Sort of. I was thinking more along the lines of "all files that have not been modified in the last 4 days", but I assume any tool or script to do one could easily do the other.

Comment: What OS are you using? Do you require `git` to do this job?

Comment: Duh, silly me, of course I don't... Thank you. (For the record: *nix)

Comment: Then I guess this should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32922585/3926735